# Is it possible to get a part-time IT job while doing Masters in the UK?

Tags: job-search, career-development, united-kingdom, part-time

I am a software developer with 3 years of experience and planning to move to the UK for an MSc in the next September session. As you know students are allowed only 20 hours per week of working, I was wondering do IT companies in the UK hire grad students.

I mainly work on Winforms, ASP.NET MVC, and raw SQL queries daily basis. As most of the projects I work on are really old I don't have any chance to work with the latest technologies. I am trying to learn and do personal projects with .NET Core, Identity framework, Docker, etc.

If you guys have any suggestions on what type of projects should I do or technologies should I learn that will give me an edge in the UK job market please share them with me.  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are these 20 hours for work related to jobs within the university such as TA or lab research assistance, etc... ? Outside the university, a small number of companies may hire part time IT workers, but you have to search for them. Or you can search for external companies that hire interns from your university job board. Another option is to go freelance.

Comment: Are you sure the 20 hour limitation actually applies to somebody who has already been presumably working full-time?

Comment: @Donald, I think he's talking about the hours limitation imposed by his student visa, not by the school.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Yes I was talking about the visa restrictions.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Any idea on the hourly rate for the part-time IT jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to search online if your looking for a salaried part time position.

If you’re looking for an hourly position then you might be able to get a job at university’s lab departments, libraries or even comp Sci department (they need to hire IT people for managing all their softwares and keeping them updo date).

If you want something more technical, I would highly recommend learning new technologies. Your chances of getting hired increases with what value you can provide to the company (even if you work part time)

There aren’t a lot of private companies looking for part timers unless there’s a specific business need like apprenticeships or co-ops. I have heard that some companies even hire part time interns during college semesters.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. Do you have any particular technology on mind that will help on job search? I mainly work with .NET stack.

Comment: Not necessarily, I would go read job descriptions of the roles you’re trying to get. They usually have a good list in their requirements and responsibilities section.